# C# - Create SQL Server table programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, create-table

I am trying to create a SQL Server table programmatically. Here is the code.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{

    try
    {
        //
        // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
        con.Open();
        //
        // The following code uses an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
        //
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE Customer(First_Name char(50),Last_Name char(50),Address char(50),City char(50),Country char(25),Birth_Date datetime);", con))
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I'm running this application second time I'm getting an exception:

> "There is already an object named 'Customer' in the database"

but when I check database I don't see such a table.
Here is my connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name ="AutoRepairSqlProvider" connectionString=
     "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AutoRepairDatabase.mdf;
     Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When I am running select query; I am getting results from existing tables so I think connection string should be OK. Hope you'll see the problem :/

Comment: Try refreshing your SQL explorer window :)

Comment: That's not possible ;) You're checking the incorrect database or the table is there and you don't see for some reason.

Comment: I'm checking correct database, because i can read data from it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the `Initial catalog` name in the connection string. Give your database name as `Initial Catalog` name.

```
<add name ="AutoRepairSqlProvider" connectionString=
     "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AutoRepairDatabase.mdf;
     Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
```

Comment: oh ! The database name was not their in him connection string . But how to show this error message `There is already an object named 'Customer' in the database` ??

Comment: @Ramesh - You've probably created 'Customer' in the 'Master' database.

Answer (score 9):

First, check whether the table exists or not. Accordingly, create table if doesn't exist.

```
var commandStr= "If not exists (select name from sysobjects where name = 'Customer') CREATE TABLE Customer(First_Name char(50),Last_Name char(50),Address char(50),City char(50),Country char(25),Birth_Date datetime)";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandStr, con))
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 4):

For managing DataBase Objects in SQL Server i would suggest using [Server Management Objects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)

Comment: This should have been the proper and accepted answer. Everything else above is ancient technology

Comment: @Fandango68, but if you want to give your application to a user, and have initial data populated, then you have to create database artifacts as part of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> Check if table have there , and drop the table , then create

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '#Customer%')
DROP TABLE #Customer CREATE TABLE Customer(First_Name char(50),Last_Name char(50),Address char(50),City char(50),Country char(25),Birth_Date datetime);", con))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like remembering SQL syntax, using [Mig#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MigSharp/) you can simply:

```
var schema = new DbSchema(ConnectionString, DbPlatform.SqlServer2014);
schema.Alter(db => db.CreateTable("Customer")
     .WithPrimaryKeyColumn("Id", DbType.Int32).AsIdentity()
     .WithNotNullableColumn("First_Name", DbType.String).OfSize(50)
     .WithNotNullableColumn("Last_Name", DbType.String).OfSize(50)
     ...);
```

If you are not sure if it already exists, call `DropIfExists` before:

```
db.Tables["Customers"].DropIfExists();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SqlCommend
{
    class sqlcreateapp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=USER-PC; Database=Emp123;User Id=sa;Password=sa123");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("create table <Table Name>(empno int,empname varchar(50),salary money);", conn);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Table Created Successfully...");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exception occured while creating table:" + e.Message + "\t" + e.GetType());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some more details

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("create table Employee (empno int,empname varchar(50),salary money);", cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblAlert.Text = "SucessFully Connected";
        cn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception eq)
    {
        lblAlert.Text = eq.ToString();
    }
}
```