# What is wrong with the syntax of this SQL statement I am using to create a table?

Tags: c#, sql, ctree, c-treeace

I keep running the code/debugger and even set break points so I can step through the code and haven't been able to find where what the syntax error is I know its within this C# method for creating a new table in the c-tree database.

Here's the code:

```
/*
   Define() method
   where specific data definitions are established also will include the definition of the table 
   being created as well as defining rows and columns of the table
*/
public static void Define()
{
    Console.WriteLine("DEFINE");

    try
    {
        //Creation of the table with the specified data types and the column Names 
        Console.WriteLine("\tCreating table...");

        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE testData (" +
           "Trackingid VARCHAR(35)," +
           "dates DATETIME," +
           "Name_Of_Recipient VARCHAR(35)," +
           "addresss VARCHAR(35)," +
           "address2 VARCHAR(31)," +
           "City VARCHAR(34)," +
           "Town VARCHAR(23)," +
           "states VARCHAR(5)," +
           "ZipCode INT )";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch(CtreeSqlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e + " could not define this table");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e + "Error the table could not be defined");
    }
}
```

Like I have mentioned before I did try and step through the code multiple times, I am assuming that it could be that I have to many column entries? or Relying on the VARCHAR data type heavily?

Exception message being thrown:

```
"        Creating table...
Ctree.Data.SqlClient.CtreeSqlException (0x7FFFB1DD): Syntax error ---> Ctree.SqlClient.Common.FcSqlException: Syntax error
   at Ctree.SqlClient.FcSqlXApi.SQLExec(FcStatement stmt, Int32 InStatementType, FcSqlDA ida, FcSqlDA oda, FcSqlCA sqlca)
   at Ctree.SqlClient.FcSqlXApi.Prepare(FcStatement stmt, FcSqlDA input_sqlda, FcSqlDA output_sqlda, Int32 fetchSize)
   at Ctree.SqlClient.FcConnection.Prepare(FcStatement statement, FcSqlDA inputDA, FcSqlDA outputDA, Int32 fetchSize)
   at Ctree.SqlClient.FcPreparedStatement..ctor(FcConnection connexion, String sql, Int32 fetchSize, Int32 timeout)
   at Ctree.Data.SqlClient.CtreeSqlCommand.InternalPrepare(Boolean resultSet)
   at Ctree.Data.SqlClient.CtreeSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Ctree.Data.SqlClient.CtreeSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at DBbeta.Program.Define() in C:\Users\WVX0DYQ\source\repos\DBbeta\DBbeta\Program.cs:line 76 could not define this table"
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Crowcoder just updated the question with the error message

Comment: [Zip codes are strings not ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893454/).

Comment: I don't know anything about ctree, but [that doesn't look at all like the documentation for creating a table.](https://docs.faircom.com/doc/ctreedn/#38364.htm)

Comment: @AceNinja1101 how do you expect to store a zip code that starts with 0...

Comment: Changing the zipcode to a character didn't really do anything @DourHighArch

Comment: [This document](https://docs.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/#createtable.htm) suggests that the create table sql syntax for c-tree ends with a `;`

Comment: `ZipCode INT` is where the syntax error occurs. It should be `INTEGER` (but as others have mentioned, zip codes should be stored as char types). Reference: https://docs.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/#33350.htm

Comment: I am referencing a tutorial from ctreeACE documentation

Comment: This is where I am getting my information in regrads to ctreeACE https://docs.faircom.com/doc/ado_net/#41986.htm

Comment: Looks like `INT` should be `INTEGER` and `DATETIME` should be `TIMESTAMP` https://docs.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/sqlref.pdf

Comment: Hmmmm why TIMESTAMP? if I need just the date? :O

Comment: You have `DATETIME` right now so I just guessed you wanted both.  Looks like your options are `DATE`, `TIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` (both date and time).

Comment: Okay I see what your saying THANK YOU @AaronDietz

Answer (score 0):

First check whether table exists or not. If not exists then it create the table.

This is running example put your values and run this

And use **INTEGER not int**  [See this for Datatypes](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp.html)

```
var commandStr= "CREATE TABLE Customer(First_Name char(50),Last_Name char(50),Address char(50),City char(50),Country char(25),Birth_Date datetime)";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandStr, con))
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Find [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589020/c-sharp-create-sql-server-table-programmatically/19589281#19589281)